# Arch Linux looks for /boot/efi when already booted

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, boot, grub2, dual-boot

I have a dual boot Arch Linux and Windows.

After a Windows update, my GRUB got lost and system was booting to `grub recovery`. From there, I managed to point GRUB to Arch Linux and boot it. However, it fails to boot completely with the message:

```
filed to listen on Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status /dev/rfkill Match
...    
failed to mount /boot/efi
# Enter recovery mode
...
```

I tried to recover my GRUB from the recovery mode (wiki is [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#UEFI_systems)):

```
mount /dev/sda5 /mnt # my Linux system
mount /dev/sda3 /efi # my EFI System partition
grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/efi --bootloader-id=GRUB
grub-config -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

That brought my GRUB back and now I can choose Arch Linux or Windows as before.

However, when I choose Arch Linux, the same error message appears `failed to mount /boot/efi`. Windows boots normally.

I checked what I have in `/boot/efi` and in fact it is empty. My `initramfs-linux.img`, `initramfs-linux-fallback.img`, `intel-ucode.img` and `vmlinux-linux.img` files are in `/boot/`.

But, in my`/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, `initrd` looks for `intel-ucode.img` and `initramfs-linux-lts.img` exactly in `/boot/` and apparently finds it.

Then I found plethora of similar problems as mine on Arch Forums (e.g. [this one](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=152284)). But I did not update Linux kernel nor did I touch anything within my Linux installation before the issue appeared. Also, as opposed to the referred post, it looks like I don't have something like `vmlinuz-arch.efi` even in `/boot/`.

I also spent some time browsing Arch Wiki. As far as I understand, the Wiki pages that refer to GRUB recovery usually propose the same procedure as I already tried but from an `arch-iso` with `arch-chroot` to my `/dev/sda5`.

So I have few questions with the topmost being: How do I recover my Arch Linux boot process?

The other, more specific, is **why `systemd` even tries to find `/boot/efi` once when GRUB phase already passed**? Isn't GRUB the one which looks for boot entries? And it looks like GRUB already picked up my Arch Linux initram (at least GRUB executed correct GRUB entry, I checked it by adding echo messages in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`).

To make it even weirder, `/boot/efi` fails to mount due to `/dev/sda2` which is my `Windows recovery environment` and **not** `/dev/sda3` which is `EFI System`:

```
$systemctl status boot-efi.mount
boot-efi.mount --- /boot/efi
Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab; generated)
Active: Failed (Result: exit-code) ...
Where: /boot/efi
What: /dev/sda2
Docs: man:fstab(5)
      man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like Windows Update did something very naughty to your EFI partition.

The main problem I see in your question is that systemd can't find /boot/efi

This is mounted using the config file `/etc/fstab`.

For whatever reason, The /boot/efi entry in /etc/fstab is looking for a file system that no longer exists.  This would be consistent with having reformatted the EFI partition and explain why you needed to reinstall grub.

You can use the command `blkid` (run as root) to find the UUID for your EFI partition.  You can then edit that into /etc/fstab.  That should fix your problem.

---

EFI is mounted so that utilities have access to read and update your EFI at runtime.

Comment: Thanks! I had my paths in `/etc/fstab` hardcoded instead of corresponding UUIDs. I found the UUIDs using `blkid` and manually replaced them for the hardcoded paths in `/etc/fstab` (`<file system>` column).